# JavaScript code not working in IE and mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a block of JavaScript code that parses json file and uploads that to server(Asp.net core). Code works fine in chrome but in IE on click event nothing happens like no errors, nothing. 
**HTML**

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-group image-preview">
     <input placeholder="File Name" id="LicenseFileText" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #fff" type="text" class="form-control " disabled="disabled">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <span class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
         <span class="fa fa-folder-open"></span> 
         <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept=".json"/>
       </span>
       <button type="button" id="Upload" class="btn btn-labeled btn-info upload"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></i> Upload</button>
     </span>
   </div>
 </form>
```

**Javascript-copies**

```
document.querySelector('.upload').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
    var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
    readBlob(startByte, endByte);
  }
}, false);
$('#files').change(function () {
  $('#LicenseFileText').val($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
});
```

//function

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {
  var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
  if ($("#LicenseFileText").val() == "") {
    NiceAlert.showNotificationError('top', 'center', 'Select a valid file');
    return ;
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
  var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
      var licenseObj = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);            
      $.ajax({
        url: "/GkAccounts/CreateLicense",                
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",                
        data: JSON.stringify(licenseObj),
        success: function (message) {
          LoadLicense();
          CheckLicenseValidity();
          NiceAlert.showNotificationSuccess('top', 'center', 'License Updated');
          $("#LicenseFileText").val("");
        },
        error: function () {
          NiceAlert.showNotificationError('top', 'center', 'Validation Failed');
          $("#LicenseFileText").val("");
        }
      });
    }
  };
  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

Comment: have you polyfilled `FileReader#readAsBinaryString`? read the note on [caniuse filereader](https://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) for IE11, it doesn't support `readAsBinaryString`- the fact that you have no errors in the developer tools console is a mystery, perhaps you aren't looking in the right place for errors

Comment: is there any alternate for readAsBinaryString?

Comment: yes, read [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) which basically tells you it's been removed from the standard, and also tells you what you should be using instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript validation tool as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to ensure maximum compatibility across all browsers, since a single omitted character like `;`, or `'`, can cause that your script won't work in specific browsers.
JSLint will give you tips on what to do and not to do to have further compatibility.
Hope this will help!